# contract violation expected: number?-Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to racket and scheme and I am attempting to map the combination of a list to the plus funtion which take each combination of the list and add them together like follows:

```
;The returned combinations 
((1 3) (2 3) (1 4) (2 4) (3 4) (1 5) (2 5) (3 5) (4 5) (1 6) (2 6) (3 6) (4    6) (5 6) (1 2) (2 2) (3 2) (4 2) (5 2) (6 2))

; expected results 
((2) (5) (5).....)
```

Unfortunately I am receiving the contract violation expected error from the following code:

```
;list of numbers 
(define l(list 1 2 3 4 5 6 2))

(define (plus l)
(+(car l)(cdr l)))

(map (plus(combinations l 2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `(cadr l)`. Not `(cdr l)` in your plus function:

```
(define (plus l) 
  (+ (car l) (cadr l)))
```

Where `x` is `(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))`:

```
(car x) => 1
(cdr x) => (cons 2 '())
(cadr x) == (car (cdr x)) => 2
```

Comment: Thank you that has fixed it and Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: @coder-noob Did that really fix it? there are a couple of bugs still present in your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of additional issues with your code, besides the error pointed out by @DanD. This should fix them:

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 2))

(define (plus lst) 
  (list (+ (car lst) (cadr lst))))

(map plus (combinations lst 2))
```

1. It's not a good idea to call a variable `l`, at first sight I thought it was a `1`. Better call it `lst` (not `list`, please - that's a built-in procedure)
2. In the expected output, weren't you supposed to produce a list of lists? add a call to `list` to `plus`
3. You're not passing `plus` in the way that `map` expects it
4. Do notice the proper way to indent and format your code, it'll help you in finding bugs